# Is it secure to pass secrets to kiosk devices using `managedConfiguration` in a Android Management policy?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise

Using the [`managedConfiguration` under `ApplicationPolicy` inside a `enterprises.policies`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#applicationpolicy), we can apply certain configurations to a managed app

Is it secure / correct to use this `managedConfiguration` to pass some secrets to the device or if I should use something else?

If not, what would be the better / more secure way to achieve this?

(FYI, I was planning to pass an API key to some [dedicated devices](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices#kiosk_mode) so that they could call some API at my server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use the managed configuration to pass an api key to dedicated devices. You can try using a security key manager like the  [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) API from Google.
Additionally, we do have an excellent guide for [best practices around API Keys management](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) from our developer documentation although it is not Android specific.